How do I apply Tailwind CSS to a specific div block and Bootstrap for the rest?
Currently, I only want to apply Tailwind CSS and React to a the "First Impressions" section. This is a div block I added recently (through the help of ChatGPT) and when I loaded the page, I noticed that the Bootstrap CSS styling was overridden by Tailwind. Removing the Tailwind CDN link allows the rest of the page to be styled as intended, albeit at the cost of the newly-added div block rendering improperly.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>MapPalette - Login</title>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/7.23.5/babel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Tailwind CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    

  <style>
    .navbar {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        /*controls brand name size in navbar*/
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

    .nav-link {
        /*controls font size and margin of nav links*/
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .navbar-brand img {
        /*brand logo sizing*/
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-right: 8px;
    }

    .app-name {
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      color: #007bff;
    }

    /* Full-width hero section */
    .hero {
      background: url('../resources/index/run-background.jpeg') no-repeat center center/cover;
      height: 80vh;
      position: relative;
    }

    .hero-content {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }

    .hero h1 {
      font-size: 4rem;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    .btn-primary {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    /* Key Features section */
    .key-features {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin: 2rem 0;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .features-image {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    /* Video container */
    .video-container {
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* About us */
    .about-us {
      padding: 3rem 0;
    }

    .about-us-description {
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: lighter;
    }

    /* First Impressions section */
    .first-impressions .card {
      border: none;
      background-color: #f8f9fa;
    }

    /* Fade-in scroll effect */
    .fade-in {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(50px);
      transition: opacity 0.8s ease-out, transform 1s ease-out;
    }

    .fade-in.show {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0);
    }

    /* Sequential rendering for Key Features */
    .col-sm-4 {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(50px);
      transition: opacity 0.8s ease-out, transform 2s ease-out;
    } 

    /* Additional hover feature */
    .col-sm-4:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      transform: scale(1.05);
    }

    /* Carousel modifications */
    .carousel-container {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 35%;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .carousel-slide {
        display: flex;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .carousel-item {
        min-width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .person-image {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        object-fit: contain;
    }

    .person-name {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .person-description {
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #666;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next {
        top: 40%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 2em;
      color: #333;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;
      padding: 0 10px;
    }

    .prev {
      left: 10px;
    }

    .next {
      right: 10px;
    }

    .scrollbar-hide::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }

    /* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
    .scrollbar-hide {
        -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
        scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light px-3">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../resources/index/mappalettelogo.png"><span style="color: #007bff;">MapPalette</span></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="login.html" class="nav-link btn btn-outline-primary">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="signup.html" class="nav-link btn btn-primary">Sign Up</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

  <!-- Hero Section -->
  <section class="hero">
    <div class="hero-content">
      <h1>Explore the World with MapPalette</h1>
      <p>Creative routes for every adventure</p>
      <a href="signup.html" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</a>
      <a href="login.html" class="btn btn-outline-light">Login</a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- First Impressions Section -->
  <section class="first-impressions fade-in">

  <div id="root">
    <!-- Your React component -->
    <script type="text/babel">
        

        // Copy the entire GalleryComponent code here
        const GalleryComponent = () => {
            const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = React.useState(null);
            const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = React.useState(0);
            const scrollContainerRef = React.useRef(null);
            
            const images = [
                "../resources/index/about_us/placeholder.jpg",
                "../resources/index/about_us/placeholder.jpg",
                "../resources/index/about_us/placeholder.jpg",
                "../resources/index/about_us/placeholder.jpg",
                "../resources/index/about_us/placeholder.jpg",
                "../resources/index/about_us/placeholder.jpg",
                "../resources/index/about_us/placeholder.jpg",
                "../resources/index/about_us/placeholder.jpg",
            ];

            const handleScroll = (e) => {
                if (scrollContainerRef.current) {
                    const container = scrollContainerRef.current;
                    const scrollPos = container.scrollLeft;
                    setScrollPosition(scrollPos);
                    
                    const itemWidth = container.offsetWidth / 3;
                    const newActiveIndex = Math.round(scrollPos / itemWidth);
                    setActiveIndex(newActiveIndex);
                }
            };

            const getItemScale = (index) => {
                if (activeIndex === null) return 0.6;
                
                const distance = Math.abs(index - activeIndex);
                
                switch (distance) {
                    case 0:
                        return 1;
                    case 1:
                        return 0.85;
                    case 2:
                        return 0.75;
                    case 3:
                        return 0.65;
                    default:
                        return 0.6;
                }
            };

            const getVerticalOffset = (index) => {
                const scale = getItemScale(index);
                return (1 - scale) * 20;
            };

            return (
                <div className="w-full h-screen bg-white relative overflow-hidden">
                    <div 
                        ref={scrollContainerRef}
                        className="flex overflow-x-auto h-full items-center snap-x snap-mandatory scrollbar-hide px-12"
                        onScroll={handleScroll}
                        style={{
                            scrollBehavior: 'smooth',
                            WebkitOverflowScrolling: 'touch'
                        }}
                    >
                        <div className="flex-shrink-0 w-[20vw]" />
                        {images.map((src, index) => (
                            <div
                                key={index}
                                className="snap-start flex-shrink-0 h-full flex items-center justify-center transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out px-2"
                                style={{
                                    width: 'auto',
                                    opacity: getItemScale(index) * 0.8 + 0.2,
                                }}
                            >
                                <div 
                                    className="relative overflow-hidden group transition-all duration-500"
                                    onMouseEnter={() => setActiveIndex(index)}
                                    style={{
                                        height: `${getItemScale(index) * 70}vh`,
                                        transform: `translateY(${getVerticalOffset(index)}%)`,
                                        transformOrigin: 'center center'
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <img
                                        src={src}
                                        alt={`Gallery image ${index + 1}`}
                                        className="h-full w-auto object-cover transition-transform duration-500 group-hover:scale-105"
                                        style={{
                                            maxWidth: 'none'
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                        <div className="flex-shrink-0 w-[20vw]" />
                    </div>

                    <div className="absolute bottom-8 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2">
                        <div className="flex space-x-0.5">
                            {images.map((_, index) => (
                                <div
                                    key={index}
                                    className={`h-px transition-all duration-300 ${
                                        activeIndex === index ? 'bg-black w-8' : 'bg-gray-300 w-4'
                                    }`}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        };

        // Render the component
        const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
        root.render(<GalleryComponent />);
    </script>
</div>
</section>

  <!-- Key Features Section -->
  <section class="container py-5 text-center">
    <div class="mb-5 fade-in">
        <h2>Why Choose MapPalette?</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-4 fade-in">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="features-image" src="../resources/index/features/maps.png" alt="">
        <h4>Creative Route Drawing</h4>
        <p>Design and follow fun, custom running routes on the map.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="features-image" src="../resources/index/features/share.png" alt="">
        <h4>Share Your Routes</h4>
        <p>Easily share your routes with friends or on social media.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="features-image" src="../resources/index/features/integration.png" alt="">
        <h4>Seamless Integration</h4>
        <p>Connect with fitness apps like Strava to track your runs.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>


Question if whether you need TailwindCSS at all. If not, but you want to retain the stylings - just copy the particular styling into your local css and that's it.

This smells like a xy-problem. Simple answer: You don't. Both CSS frameworks by default expect to be the only CSS framework that you use, therefor both make basic decisions that will contradict each other and therefor you normally do not mix them (as they are out of the box). If I'd be in you position, I'd probably keep Bootstrap and recreate the styles that you use from tailwind in a special CSS file instead of using the tailwind classes. Out of interest: It seems you do not use a build step for your React based component - why?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Don't use the CDN versions. Instead, import the Tailwind / Bootstrap libs as normal, but scope them within your own class to prevent them 'leaking'.
In your main .css file;
.tw-only {
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
}

In your html:
<div class="tw-only">Tailwind styles are only applied within this element</div>

